# Proble in my page because not working audio onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a page which has 5 button elements in the html document call boton and I want them to sound when I click on them. But it doesn't work.

This is the javascript code

```
const rollSound = new Audio("./sounds/button-click-off-click.mp3");
document.getElementsByClassName('boton').addEventListener("click", e => rollSound.play());
```

And the HTML

```
<ul class="barra">
  <li><a href="#fotos" class="boton">Galería</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/" class="boton" onmousedown="audio.play()">Sesiones/Horarios</a></li>
  <li><a href="#video" class="boton" onmousedown="audio.play()">Artículos</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/" class="boton" onmousedown="audio.play()">Información personal</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/" class="boton" onmousedown="audio.play()">Redes Sociales</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should select the elements when DOM has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this to make it sound. Different key sequences can be combined into a wonderful piano song. And here is a great reference for your piano work, I hope you enjoy it

Piano: https://github.com/Wscats/piano

Demo: https://wscats.github.io/piano/build

```js
const audios = [
    new Audio('https://wscats.github.io/piano/build/samples/piano/a84.mp3'),
    new Audio('https://wscats.github.io/piano/build/samples/piano/a89.mp3'),
    new Audio('https://wscats.github.io/piano/build/samples/piano/a85.mp3'),
    new Audio('https://wscats.github.io/piano/build/samples/piano/a73.mp3'),
    new Audio('https://wscats.github.io/piano/build/samples/piano/a79.mp3'),
    new Audio('https://wscats.github.io/piano/build/samples/piano/a80.mp3'),
    new Audio('https://wscats.github.io/piano/build/samples/piano/a65.mp3'),
];
let i = 0;
let body = document.body;
for (; i < audios.length; i++) {
    let button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerText = i;
    const audio = audios[i];
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        audio.play();
    });
    body.appendChild(button);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a list of elements on which you try to attach an event listener.

The [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method returns an array like object with DOM elements.

So, if you want each item to have the event attached, you have to loop through all of them and add listeners separately.

Something like this:

```
const rollSound = new Audio("./sounds/button-click-off-click.mp3");

const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.boton');
elements.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () => {
 rollSound.play();
}));
```